# Dynamic text source is lost when changing map layout in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layouts, dynamic-text

I'm trying to make arcpy custom toolbox where one of the tools is to make a Map Layout. I'm using dynamic text to change Map Information based on the feature class. It should be something like this:

```
<dyn type="table" property="value" mapFrame="Muka Peta Map Frame" mapMemberUri="CIMPATH=map/atributpeta.xml" field="Provinsi" delimiter=" "/>
```

But then after I run the toolbox for the second time, none of the information is showing and the dynamic text is changing into this (mapMemberUri is gone)

```
<dyn type="table" property="value" mapFrame="Muka Peta Map Frame" mapMemberUri="" field="Provinsi" delimiter=" "/>
```

I was wondering is there an alternative to make a dynamic text stay as it is?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: At the moment you are presenting text formatting tags but no ArcPy code.